# Null Reference exception on record insertion in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework-6, nullreferenceexception

I have a simple 2 tabled database consisting of Users and Groups. Here are the columns of the tables:

**Users**:

- UserID
- UserName
- GroupID

**Groups**:

- GroupID
- GroupName

And here are the generated classes:

```
public partial class Group
{
    public Group()
    {
        this.Users = new HashSet<User>();
    }

    public int GroupID { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

-

```
public partial class User
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> GroupID { get; set; }

    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
}
```

I need to make a method which inserts an user into a given group. If the group doesnt exist, it should create it. I am using Entity Framework. Here is some code:

```
public class Entry
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        using (var dbContext = new UserSystemEntities())
        {
            var user = new User();
            user.UserName = "h4x0r";

            AddUserToGroup(dbContext, "Admins", user);

            Console.WriteLine("User {0} added successfully.", user.UserName);
        }
    }

    public static void AddUserToGroup(UserSystemEntities dbContext, string groupName, User user)
    {
        using (var dbTransaction = dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            var group = dbContext.Groups.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GroupName == groupName);

            try
            {
                if (group == null)
                {
                    var newGroup = new Group();
                    newGroup.GroupName = groupName;

                    dbContext.Groups.Add(newGroup);                     
                }

                dbContext.Groups.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GroupName == group.GroupName).Users.Add(user);
                dbContext.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error occured! " + ex.message);
                dbTransaction.Rollback();
            }

            dbTransaction.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

There is a problem with adding the user in the group at:

```
dbContext.Groups.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GroupName == group.GroupName).Users.Add(user);
```

throwing a Null Reference Exception and I just cant figure out why. Starring at it for about 20 minutes now and still cant find an answer. Why do I miss?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to get a group from your DB which doesn't exist and attach a user to it.

If you attach new group to the context which you are doing inside an `if` clause it won't be saved to the DB automatically, that's why when you call `FirstOrDefault` method, which queries the database, it fails as your record is not there. So when you have a group (either from a DB or newly created) you can just use your `group` variable and attach a `User` to it.

You should modify your code to the following:

```
    var group = dbContext.Groups.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GroupName == groupName);

    try
    {
        if (group == null)
        {
            group  = new Group();
            group.GroupName = groupName;

            dbContext.Groups.Add(group);                     
        }

        group.Users.Add(user);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error occured! " + ex.message);
        dbTransaction.Rollback();
    }

    dbTransaction.Commit();
```

Comment: It still results in Null Reference Exception. The 'group' varible has a null value.

Comment: Oh, I fixed it. We just exchange 'newGroup' with 'group' and everything works fine. I cant believe I missed something that simple. Yet, starring for 30 minutes didnt do much good. :D Thank you!